# directX creating the swapchain

Tags: c++, directx

In my book there i code to create swap chain.

```
IDXGIDevice * dxgiDevice = 0;
mD3dDevice->QueryInterface( __uuidof( IDXGIDevice ),( void ** ) & dxgiDevice );

IDXGIAdapter * dxgiAdapter = 0;
dxgiDevice->GetParent( __uuidof( IDXGIAdapter ),( void ** ) & dxgiAdapter );

IDXGIFactory * dxgiFactory = 0;
dxgiAdapter->GetParent( __uuidof( IDXGIFactory ),( void ** ) & dxgiFactory );

dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChain( mD3dDevice, & sd, & mSwapChain );
```

For this code there is no explanation, i check few mor books and there is too, noo explanation for this code.

Please help mi with this. 
I realy dont understand what doing GetParent method.
idxgiDevice extend idxgiObject.
parent for idxgiDevice is idxgiObject, why they use pointer to idxgiFacory  as a parametr.

And i dont know that i understand the queryInterface good

Please help mi with this

Answer (score 15):

This code is for creating the swap chain with DirectX 11 or later version of the interfaces, and this pattern is specifically designed to ensure that the DXGI factory instance you use is the one that was actually used when you created the Direct3D 11 device.

Basically, when you first created the Direct3D 11 device, you had the option of providing the `IDXGIAdapter` instance to use. Most people pass `nullptr` or `NULL` here and just let it create a device on the default adapter in the system. To finish setting up the swap chain, however, you need the DXGI factory instance. You could in theory create one yourself using `DXGICreateFactory1` but you could easily mess up and get the 'wrong one' by using `DXGICreateFactory` or maybe `DXGICreateFactory2` with the wrong flags.

Instead, the safest thing to do is get the `IDXGIDevice` from your `ID3D11Device` using the standard COM [IUnknown::QueryInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521.aspx):

```
IDXGIDevice * dxgiDevice = 0;
HRESULT hr = mD3dDevice->QueryInterface( __uuidof( IDXGIDevice ),( void ** ) & dxgiDevice );
if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
```

Then get the `IDXGIAdapter` from the `IDXGIDevice` using [IDXGIObject::GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174542.aspx):

```
IDXGIAdapter * dxgiAdapter = 0;
hr = dxgiDevice->GetParent( __uuidof( IDXGIAdapter ),( void ** ) & dxgiAdapter );
if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
```

Then get the `IDXGIFactory` from the `IDXGIAdapter` using [IDXGIObject::GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174542.aspx) again:

```
IDXGIFactory * dxgiFactory = 0;
hr = dxgiAdapter->GetParent( __uuidof( IDXGIFactory ),( void ** ) & dxgiFactory );
if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
```

Now you have the `IDXGIFactory` associated with your Direct3D 11 device no matter how it was created. Remember that COM reference counting means you have references to all these objects now you have to cleanup:

```
dxgiFactory->Release();
dxgiAdapter->Release();
dxgiDevice->Release();
```

Note that `IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain` is the DirectX 11.0 way of creating the swap chain, and you'd get basically the same results if you had used [D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476083.aspx) rather than [D3D11CreateDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476082.aspx) in the first place. For DirectX 11.1 or later systems, you would consider using `IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForHwnd` instead for Win32 desktop apps. For Windows Store apps, Windows phone 8, and Xbox One, you'd always use `IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow`.

For a Win32 desktop application, you'd follow the code above with something like:

```
IDXGIFactory2* dxgiFactory2 = 0;
hr = dxgiFactory->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IDXGIFactory2), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&dxgiFactory2) );
if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    // This system has DirectX 11.1 or later installed, so we can use this interface
    dxgiFactory2->CreateSwapChainForHwnd( /* parameters */ );
    dxgiFactory2->Release();
}
else
{
    // This system only has DirectX 11.0 installed
     dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChain( /* parameters */ );
}
```

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) and the Direct3D tutorial sample [Win32 desktop app version](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/Direct3D11Tutorials).

> DirectX12 usage explicitly disallows this code pattern. For more details, see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but i still cent understand one thing. Can you explain me how the method GetParent works?? Parent For IDXGI::Device is IDXGIObject, because IDXGIDevice inherit from IDXGIObject. Why as a parameter we givent ID of adapter interface. Please Explain this, this is hard for me, I cant find good explain

Comment: It was done for simplicity of the API. ``DXGIObject::GetParent`` could always return an ``IUnknown`` or perhaps a ``DXGIObject``, and you'd have to use ``QueryInterface`` to get anything useful from that. Therefore, ``GetParent`` just takes the UUID you want so it can do the equivalent of the ``QueryInterface`` for you in the same call. This also provides a measure of type-safety since you are making assumptions about the child-parent relationship using it.

Comment: What is not clear is how calling QueryInterface on md3dDevice object, gets the correct DXGIDevice object ? Could we have called QueryInterface on IUnknown and still get the correct DXGIDevice object ?